# when i connect two alternator together how much is

Tags: alternator

I saw in large power plant a lot of huge generators connected together so i wondering

when i connect two generators together in parallel ( both at 120 volts ) at same phase , frequency and speed, how much is the total volts ?( will it be 240 120+120=240?

Comment: matching current is critical when put in parallel so it must be sensed along with V and phase.

Comment: `huge generators connected together` ... were the generators really connected together?

Comment: @jsotola. In a power plant they would be synchronous, but OP has not mentioned how he intends to keep them in phase, else things go BOOM.

Comment: You CANNOT connect generators in parallel unless they are phase synchronized ....if they are in sync, then you can draw more current (power) from them.

Answer (score 2):

If you properly synchronize them before connecting them in parallel, it will be 120V because they are in parallel, not in series.

If you don't properly synchronize them, then something will go bang and you will be lucky to get any volts at all.

Comment: thanks all for your answers , what i understood form answers that either i connect the in parallel to get double the current or in series to get double the volts i can not do both in the same time ( combine volts and amps when connect two generators together , is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, connect two in parallel for double the current - this is essentially how the national electricity grids work.  In theory, you could connect two in series, but unless you can get the phases synchronized, the voltage will vary wildly.  It would be easier to connect two generators in parallel, and use a step-up transformer.

Answer (score 1):

The voltages don’t add when in parallel, and I don’t remember seeing two alternators connected in series - batteries yes, resistors yes etc